# Where can I find the iOS 10 font list on apple documents?

Tags: ios, iphone, fonts

There used be an official web page on apple support like [iOS 6 font list](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5484) or [iOS 7 font list](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5878). But there're no such page for the later iOS versions and the iOS 6 and iOS 7 font lists are not available any more.

My question here is: Is there any official web page from apple that shows which font we can use on which iOS version? I know there's some thing like [iOS Font List](http://iosfontlist.com/). Just want to know if there's an official way to get this information(all the pre-installed fonts and downloadable fonts).

If there's not, how does iosfontlist.com get those information?

Thanks!

Comment: Not "official", http://iosfonts.com/ , all you needed was to search "ios fonts" on google. here is the officla one : https://developer.apple.com/fonts/

Comment: Hi @Sneak Thanks for your reply. The official site you supplied has no font list, it just says San Francisco, not a list of available fonts(pre-installed fonts + downloadable fonts). And I did search "ios fonts" on google before I post a question here, and I can see there's iosfonts.com iosfontlist.com, but my question is: Is there an official page from apple which list all available fonts of all iOS versions?

Comment: If you want to specifically check for iOS 10, I don't think theres a "website" or "list" for it offically, probably why there are tons of unofficial ones out there. You should check multiple other threads posting the same question , the solution usually on them is to run the code in the app and print out the available fonts in the project. Edit: found this link for you (not checked if trusty) https://gist.github.com/nickcheng/820386397ede9eba4cfafec1a37fb51a

Comment: Is there any specific use case for you to do this?

Comment: @KrishnaCA Thanks for reply. Our designers need a list like that, so they can choose fonts from it. I know iosfontlist.com should solve the problem in my case, but if there's no official documents, where does iosfontlist.com get those information? Yeah, we can create a demo app, show all the pre-installed fonts, but what about the downloadable fonts?

Comment: @KyleXie, you can always check whether the given downloadable UIFont is supported or not. I am not sure about list of downloadable fonts supported. If you want, I can give you that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there's no such official web site for iOS 10. But you can find a similar one here: https://developer.apple.com/fonts/system-fonts/#document

The `Preinstalled fonts` is helpful.